# Nullable TimeSpan? to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable, timespan

How do I convert this C# line of code to a TimeSpan from Nullable TimeSpan
as DateStamp is Nullable DateTime

```
 TimeSpan? timestamp = DateTime.Now - modelXyz.DateStamp
```

Comment: What if `DateStamp` is actually null? Can we assume that will not happen?

Answer (score 12):

```
TimeSpan? timestamp = DateTime.Now - modelXyz.DateStamp;
if(timestamp.HasValue)
{
    TimeSpan nonNullableTS = timestamp.Value;
}
```

Comment: Or of course: `if (modelXyz.DateStamp.HasValue) { TimeSpan nonNullableTS = DateTime.Now - modelXyz.DateStamp.Value; /* use the time span here */ }`

Comment: From another question, I got this 

DateTime timeStamp = modeXyz.DateStamp.GetValueOrDefault();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Is this right?

Comment: Sure.  You're basically trying to understand how "nullable's" work.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx